# How to Object Data from child component to parent component

Tags: angular, components

I want to pass object data from child component to parent component.

```
<section class="grey_bg">
<app-search></app-search>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let contest of contests">
            <td>{{contest.contest_date}}</td>
            <td>{{contest.prize_pool}}</td>
            <td>{{contest.points}}</td>
            <td>${{contest.entry_fee}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Get data from Child Component Search Component that has selected app-search that has contest data

```
this.authService.getUserContests().subscribe(
    contests => {
      this.contests = contests.data

    }
```

Comment: Given info is incomplete. Provide what have you been done so far?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest ways to share information between parent and child components can be found in the [Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) provided by the Angular team.

The specific technique you should focus on, is an `Output()` via `EventEmitter` as described [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-listens-for-child-event).